# Code Igniter- Batch Insert function inserts null fields in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Whenever i try to insert data, the fields of the two of the columns are null. ONLY the auto incremented(of course)MainReqID and the last column had the fields.
Here's my Controller..

```
public function insert_main($data,$orgs){
  $this->db->insert('insert_main',$data);
  $getID = $this->db->insert_id();

  $ctr=1;
  $insertorg = array();
  foreach($i=0; $i<count($orgs); $i++){
     $insertorg[] = array(
       'OrgID'=>$ctr[$i],
       'MainID'=>$getID[$i],
       'Level'=>'1234'[$i]
     );
  $ctr++;
  }
  $this->db->insert_batch('insert_mainreq',$insertorg);
}
```

here's what it looks like in database...

```
MainReqID | OrgID | MainID | Level
1         | null  | null   | 1234
2         | null  | null   | 1234
3         | null  | null   | 1234
4         | null  | null   | 1234
5         | null  | null   | 1234.. and so on..
```

i need something like this..

```
MainReqID | OrgID | MainID | Level
1         | 1     | 3      | 1234
2         | 2     | 3      | 1234
3         | 3     | 3      | 1234
4         | 4     | 3      | 1234
5         | 5     | 3      | 1234.. and so on..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `$getID` is not an array but you are adding `$getID[i]`.  This surely will not work.  The same with `$ctr`.  This is an integer but you are trying `$ctr[i]`. The same thing is happening with `Level`.

```
public function insert_main($data,$orgs){
  $this->db->insert('insert_main',$data);
  **$getID** = $this->db->insert_id();

  **$ctr=1;**
  $insertorg = array();
  foreach($i=0; $i<count($orgs); $i++){
     $insertorg[] array(
       'OrgID'=>**$ctr[$i]**,
       'MainID'=>**$getID[$i]**,
       'Level'=>**'1234'[$i]**
     );
  $ctr++;
  }
  $this->db->insert_batch('insert_mainreq',$insertorg);
}
```

You could try this,  I am not sure what you are trying to do with OrgId and MainID but:

```
public function insert_main($data,$orgs){
  $this->db->insert('insert_main',$data);
  $getID = $this->db->insert_id();

  $insertorg = array();
  foreach($i=0; $i<count($orgs); $i++){
     $insertorg[] array(
       'OrgID'=> $i,
       'MainID'=>$getID,
       'Level'=>'1234'
     );
  }
  $this->db->insert_batch('insert_mainreq',$insertorg);
}
```

Keep in mind that `$this->db->insert_id();` will return the id of the last row inserted if there are more than one row.

Comment: I updated my answer to get what you are showing in your second example.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
public function insert_main($data,$orgs){
$this->db->insert('insert_main',$data);
$getID = $this->db->insert_id();

$insertorg = array();
    foreach($i=0; $i<count($orgs); $i++)
    {
    $insertorg[] = array(
        'OrgID'=> $i,
        'MainID'=>$getID,
        'Level'=>'1234'
    );
    }           
$this->db->insert_batch('insert_mainreq',$insertorg);

}
```

Comment: I have changed `  $insertorg[] = array`